# What is a full validation in Codeigniter for textarea editor?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am interesting in a full and correct validation form in Codeigniter for the more secure site.
U use **CI 2.3**.

In official tutorial, I found the special functions for preparing and validating form.
I have a textarea editor, what is a right sequence of validate this field? `(trim|xss_clean|required)` or any sequence?

I allow users to enter only a few tags HTML - others need to be removed including tags java. php.

Comment: trim() only removes external whitespaces, "required" just validates if the field is filled or not. You're looking for a subset of xss_clean(), which  is not "validation" but "sanitation"

Comment: Advise me please a hard validation :)

Comment: do you want it to error if certain tags are present, or do you want to sanitize the entered text and remove certain tags?

Comment: I want secure against Sql injection and remove the tags that are not allowed.

Comment: Are you using active record? If yes you are safe from SQL injection. For the HTML you need to create filter that fit your needs I am sure there is already one or two just google them out.

Comment: Yes, I use. Can you advise a good filter for Jquery TE(editor)

Comment: I also need a good example of validation textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the validation I am using for textaria : `trim|required|max_length[1000]`